# Is mediocrely a word?

Tags: word-usage

I've checked some online dictionaries and have not found it in some while it does exist in others and so wonder if it's a word or not and unsure how to be sure about such things? Given a word, how can one be sure it exists? Is there an official online dictionary that can be trusted?

Comment: Productive suffixes like *-ly* always form words when applied according to their rules. That’s why they’re called “productive”.

Comment: So why do some appear in the two (online) dictionaries I use most often and some do not. It appears it would be trivial to add all of them.

Comment: It would not be trivial to add all possible words that derive from all possible productive affixes, and it would nonsensical to do so. That would be like adding all possible hyphenated "adjective-noun" combinations. Language is inherently combinatoric in an unbounded fashion.

Comment: Furthermore, it is a grave error of the first degree to think that any dictionary contains all words. None do nor ever can: that is not how language works. Neither does a word's absence from this or that dictionary in any way constitute some sort of *ipso facto* proof that it is not an actual word, nor even in at least a few cases does a word’s presence there prove that it is one.

Comment: @tchrist What degree of error is it to write "None do" instead of "none does"?

Comment: @tchrist It seems like you're over-dramatizing a response to what is at heart an innocent and statistically well founded curiosity. For instance, the words `superbly` and `superiorly` (an antonym of sorts) do appear on dictionary.com while the aforementioned does not, all three words are rather commonly used. Your insights would be more appropriate for edge cases like very rare words and in the first case, very strange and unlikely use of productive suffixes.

Comment: @deadrat That would be an error of the second person, for it is yours not mine.

Comment: There are a number of books that cover the history of the *Oxford English Dictionary*.  I recommend that you read one or more to get an idea of how lexicographers grappled with the problem of determining what was a word and which ones were worthy of inclusion in their dictionary.  It's a fascinating look at trying to solve an intractable problem that's easily stated and seemingly easy to solve.

Comment: @tchrist Don't think so.  The sense here is clearly "not one," but my intent is better illustrated by zehelvion's following comment.  There are many grave errors one may make in this life.  Misunderstanding the construction of dictionaries isn't one of them.  And do we still have the death penalty for errors in the first degree?

Comment: @deadrat I'm sorry that you don't understand the difference between not any do and not one does.

Comment: @tchrist I'd say I was sorry that you don't understand the difference in phrasing between your first comment and your last.  But I'm not.

Comment: There's grammar and there's style. adding '-ly' is mostly legal to add to any (longer) adjective. But, as you've had the idea to ask the question, you probably have the inner feeling as a native speaker that 'mediocrely' is an infelicitous sounding word. I would suggest not using it, and use something else. 'in a mediocre manner' sounds a little better to me.

Comment: Love your insight, @Mitch, doing something *correctly*, isn't the sole condition for *good* quality. It sometimes ends up looking rather mediocrely. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no "official" source of English vocabulary.  Generally, you're allowed to form adverbs by adding *-ly* to adjectives, so your first guess should be that *mediocrely* meaning "in a mediocre manner" is a word.  Then check to see whether people use it like this from *[Larry McMurtry and the West: An Ambivalent Relationship](https://books.google.com/books?id=SLVg2LO-y9EC&pg=PA8&dq=%22mediocrely%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTk8DZ_MfJAhWGzz4KHb9hBwoQ6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=%22mediocrely%22&f=false)* by Mark Busby:

> In high school I did a surprising number of things **mediocrely**.
>   Among these were baseball, basketball, 4-H work, tennis, track, ready
>   writing, editorial writing, extemporaneous speech, drama, declaiming,
>   trombone playing, and debating.

The google reports almost 40K uses online.  Even allowing for instances of debate over whether it's a word, that leaves enough to validate your first guess.

Comment: How did you find that quote?

Comment: It's a wonderful example, isn't it?  Contrasting the quantity of activities with the quality of the performance of them.  I used the Ngram viewer at https://books.google.com/ngrams, which allows you to find usages and compare different usages as they appear over time in google books.

Comment: This is indeed a fascinating tool. It feels like it would do me good service when this sort of question comes up again especially since the words are there even if they continue to elude any dictionaries' definition. For instance you could find a word like `Wolven`which is often used in phantasy literature to refer to wolf-like humanoids. Very interesting and many thanks.

Comment: Also good for checking idiomatic usages.  Is it "different *from*", "different *than*", or "different *that*"?

Comment: Not sure this is clear, lets say we have a sentence that express `A` isn't equivalent to `B` and we want to use one of the three options you listed. How would one apply ngrams to this situation?

Comment: @zehelvion In the text box to the right of the label "Graph these comma-separated phrases:" enter the following: different from,different than,different that

Comment: So what is the best word instead of 'mediocrely'? 'average'? (it must be an adverb by the way)

Answer (score 2):

The Oxford English Dictionary has an entry for *mediocrely* since OED Third Edition, June 2001. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/251632

[image]